# apply function on each data frames names stored in character vector

Tags: r, apply

I have data frames in my environment, and I have stored the names of the same in a character vector.

```
ldf <- names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame))))
```

when I print ldf, it has a structure similar to this:

```
>ldf
[1] "tdf1"           "tdf2"
[3] "tdf3"
```

I want to remove rows that has many na's from each of these data frames. I have created a function as follows:

```
remna <- function(df) {
  df$countofna <- apply(df[,c(1:length(df))], 1,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
  df <- df[df$countofna <=3, ]
  df$countofna <- NULL
  df <- df[1:nrow(df)-1, ]
}
```

How do i apply the `remna` function on each of the dataframes with names stored in `ldf`.  Without using `ldf`, I tried using a for loop:

```
for (i in names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame))))) {
  remna(i)
}
```

however this fails at executing remna with the following error:

```
Error in df[, c(1:length(df))] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

The function `remna` works perfectly on individual data frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to load the datasets in a `list` with `mget` and use `rowSums` to create a logical vector for keeping/removing the rows from each of the dataset

```
out <- lapply(mget(ldf), function(dat) dat[rowSums(is.na(dat)) <= 3,, drop = FALSE])
```

If the original objects needs to be updated, then use `list2env` (not recommended though)

```
list2env(out, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Super...works very well.  Could you please help with why `list2env` is not recommended?

Comment: @Apricot. Generally, it is not a good practise to have multiple objects in the global env.  Instead you can read the files directly into a list, (`lst1 <- lapply(files, read.csv)`)`, process everythin in the `list` env itself and then write the output. directly from `list` instead of all those object creation in the global env

Comment: many thanks...quite helpful.  Since my remna function has many other data wrangling i have used the following `out <- lapply(mget(ldf), function(dat) remna(dat))`  which worked perfectly.  Thank you for your additional comment on using list.